# How to include JavaScript for a specific browser?

Tags: javascript, ipad, browser, include

Including a css sheet is easy and works well with the code below.  However this must not be a good way to include a javascript file because I get an error when I view it in the iPad.  Something about an unclosed  tag.  I assume I'm getting nested  tags by doing it this way.  What should I be doing instead?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
//Sniff out iPads
if (navigator.userAgent.indexOf('iPad') != -1) {
    document.write('<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/styles/browser/ipad.css" media="screen, print" />');
    document.write('<script src="/scripts/ipad.js" type="text/javascript" />');
}
<script>
```

Comment: You forgot the closing script tag

Comment: You're right.  But only here in the post.  The syntax is correct in the real file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the `ipad.js` you can detect inside the javascript.  For the CSS just use [conditional comments](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537512%28VS.85%29.aspx) (if you're supporting older IE versions) and the [`media` attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/html/element/link) to exclude loading it in IE and other browers:

```
<!--[if !IE]>-->
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/styles/browser/ipad.css" media="only screen and (max-device-width: 480px)" />
<![endif]-->
```